# Expand the size of swap partition

Tags: swap

I did some partition size expansions of my centOs system and recover boot loader and file system successfully.I also changed the location and expanded the swap (5GB to 8GB) partition along with above deeds. Now the file system looks like this. 
[image]
 
The problem is swap doesn't show it's full size. (look at the red circle. thought the used space is 0, unused space is still 5GB ). I want to fix this.

Here is the result of free -m

```
[root@localhost ~]# free -m
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          3711        700       3010          0         71        298
-/+ buffers/cache:        330       3380
Swap:         4999          0       4999
```

Here is the uuid of swap

`/dev/sda7: UUID="52485c83-3929-4f5b-bd1c-60492ebd1e5c" TYPE="swap"`

will the command `mkswap -U 52485c83-3929-4f5b-bd1c-60492ebd1e5c` help me here. Else what must I do?

Comment: Try this, 'swapon -a' and 'swapon -s'

Comment: Thanks Ram.  Don't I want to swapoff? Can you explain it little bit? I'm little bit new to this.

Comment: You will need `swapoff` only if your swap is in use (but it won't do any harm if the swap was already off). If you just have resized your partitions, they are probably still unmounted so you don't need `swapoff`, but if you have restarted since then, your swap could have been mounted again.

Comment: Yes, you can swapoff, no issue. But make sure that you turn it **ON** back.
swapon commands makes sure that all your swap partition which is listed in /etc/fstab are turned ON & available for the system to use.

Note: Its not good practice running Linux without SWAP partition

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Disable the swap with `swapoff /dev/sda7`
2. Re-initialize the swap partition to use its full size: `mkswap /dev/sda7`
3. Re-enable the swap: `swapon /dev/sda7`

Note that `mkswap` generates a new partition `UUID` when run. This can prevent the new swap partition from being used normally, if it is referenced by `UUID` in `/etc/fstab` or elsewhere. If you want to keep the original `UUID` for your swap partition, you can specify that in step 2:

```
mkswap -U 52485c83-3929-4f5b-bd1c-60492ebd1e5c /dev/sda7
```

Comment: Thanks Dmitry, Are you sure that the `mkswap` command without specifying the `uuid` will work correctly? Will uuid be changed? If current uuid changes, will it effect badly to the file system?

Comment: Fair remark, I have updated my answer. Personally I don't use UUIDs, but your system might.